# Create PDF error with wkhtmltopdf in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm try to create pdf using wkhtmltopdf but that gave me to me unreadable file as bellow. create pdf don't show any  error to me. This my output pdf file look like
i can't understand what wrong with.

This my out put in wkhtmltopdf

```
Creating temp html file : C:\Windows\Temp\_in6991.tmp.html
Started to create PDF.
Executing to create PDF.
Executing command :""D:/programe/wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf" --dpi 100 -O Landscape -s A4 --margin-top 20 --footer-font-size 8 --footer-center "Page [page] of [topage]"" C:\Windows\Temp\_in6991.tmp.html D:/work/trunk/client\templates\templates_c\test1.pdf
Finished creation.
Deleting temp html file : C:\Windows\Temp\_in6991.tmp.html
PDF generated in 0.6866 seconds.
```

[image]

Comment: Do you send the `Content-Type: application/pdf` header?

Comment: The part of the pdf to be seen looks good, merely the wrong viewer/renderer. How do you open it?

Comment: thanks Maerlyn and mkl for help to me i forget to set header as application/pdf

Comment: @Maerlyn Please add your comment as an answer so it can be accepted, you will receive glory and fame!

Answer (score 2):

Your output is correct, but you don't tell the browser how to interpret it, so it falls back to the default text/html.

You need to send the `Content-Type: application/pdf` header so it know what you're sending.